# JSON.parse throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I am trying to get customer details in a Laravel POS application. I am sending customer cell number via AJAX to serch and returning details from controller. When ever I am trying to apply JSON.parse on returned data from server I am getting:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

I cant find errors in my code. I have searched product in exact same way from the server which works fine. Below is my code sample:

**My Ajax Function**

```
  function customersearch(){
        var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();
        var baseUrl=document.getElementById("baseUrl").value;
        var url=baseUrl+"/sales/searchcustomer";
        var id=document.getElementById("customercell").value;

        console.log(id);

        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
              url:url,
              data: {id:id},
              datatype:'json',
              success: function(data) {
                    var returndata =JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(returndata);
                    var id=returndata[0].id;
                    if(id == "undefined") {
                          alert("No Customer found");
                    }
                    else {
                          document.getElementById("cname").value = returndata[0].fname;
                          document.getElementById("cid").value = returndata[0].id;
                    }     
              }
        });
  }
```

**My Controller Function:**

```
  public function searchcustomer(Request $request){
        $searchingkey = $request->input( 'id' );

        //var_dump($searchingkey);

        $customer = DB::table('customers')
                    ->where('cellno', $searchingkey)
                    ->get(['id','fname']);

        var_dump($customer);

        if (count($customer) == 0) {
              $data = "No data returned"; // empty result
        }
        else {
              $data = $customer;
        }

        return json_encode($data);
  }
```

**Response of var_dump($customer) in Network XHR**

```
array(1) {
          [0]=>
              object(stdClass)#221 (2) {["id"]=>string(1) "1"
                                        ["fname"]=>string(5) "Ahnaf"}}

[{"id":"1","fname":"Ahnaf"}]
```

IF I dont apply JSON.parse on the returned data in ajax Function and just print the data variable like:

```
var returndata =data;
console.log(returndata);
```

this gives output in the consol like:

```
array(1) {
         [0]=>
         object(stdClass)#221 (2) {
         ["id"]=>string(1) "1"
         ["fname"]=>string(5) "Ahnaf"
         }
        }
[{"id":"1","fname":"Ahnaf"}]
```

Comment: Could you please attach log of `data` variable received from the server? Because seems like client just receiving invalid response.

Comment: see my edit. the client is receiving data.

Comment: The last code block(which is server response) is invalid JSON so it fails to parse, client should only receive last line of provided reponse.

Comment: U mean to say json_encode is giving wrong output !!!!! How can i fix json_encode :o ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP expert, you should browse StackOverflow for related questions but doesn't look like it's problem with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The [jquery docs for the `ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) say that the `dataType` parameter is spelled with a capital `T`.

You have this:

```
datatype:'json'
```

Try changing it to this:

```
dataType:'json'
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: strangely using 'T' results in client not receiving any data :o

Comment: @Ahnaf: Also add an `error` callback, e.g. `error: function(xhr,status,message) { console.log(status+' '+message); },`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `first()` instead of `get()`.
That should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo` rather than `return` for ajax response

My Controller Function:

```
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Also dataType must be

```
dataType: "json" // but remove this line because your already have JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: tried this man.. not working ..  my guess is json encode is giving me a invalid json but dnt know why ..